# How to check if radiobutton is selected (javascript, html)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to check if a radio button is selected or not. If the "morn_before" radiobutton is selected, the data will be stored as "2", but if the "morn_after" radiobutton is selected instead, the data will be stored as "1".
Currently my code show below is not working. For example when i select the "morn_before" radiobutton, it doesnt print "morn_before checked true" in the console, despite me putting console.log("morn_before checked true") in that if statement.

HTML:

```
<div class="radiobutton">
            <input type="radio" id="morn_before"  name="morn_time" value="morn_before">
            <label for="morn_before">Before Food</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="morn_after"  name="morn_time" value="morn_after">
            <label for="morn_after">After Food</label><br><br>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function check() {
    let user=firebase.
    auth().currentUser;
    let uid;
    if(user!=null){
        uid=user.uid;
    }
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    if(document.getElementById("morn_before").checked){
        console.log("morn_before checked true");
        firebase.database().ref(uid).child('/radiobutton/').child('/morn_time/').set("2");

    }  
    else if(document.getElementById("morn_after").checked){
        firebase.database().ref(uid).child('/radiobutton/').child('/morn_time/').set("1");
    }
}
check();
```

Comment: What you mean by "_not working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: For example when i select the "morn_before" radiobutton, it doesnt print "morn_before checked true" in the console, despite me putting console.log("morn_before checked true") in that if statement.

Comment: Where is the event listner for the `morn_before` click or change? Have you posted all the relevant code? I see you have a `check` method, but there is no connection I can see atm.

Comment: Is it possible to do without an event listener like in C#?

Comment: Then you have to submit the form and write something that understands how to read submitted info, which is something you don't seem to be familiar with.

Comment: If you are asking how to write a value into Firebase, that is WELL BEYOND the original scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript for this. You can have a completely different display than the stored value.

```
<div class="radiobutton">
  <input type="radio" id="morn_before"  name="morn_time" value="2">
  <label for="morn_before">Before Food</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="morn_after"  name="morn_time" value="1">
  <label for="morn_after">After Food</label><br><br>
 </div>
```

Should produce the same result. The only improvement would be to set one of these to default true, in case the user chose neither. But that'd be up to you.

ADDITIONAL INFO: You are not supposed to read a radio button group that way.

You should go over some basics of HTML INPUT tag such as

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button-using-javascript/

Comment: How do I store the data in the firebase database with this HTML code?  Is it something like this:                                                                                                                                      var x=document.getElementById("morn_before").checked       firebase.database().ref(uid).child('/radiobutton/').child('/morn_time/').set(x);

Comment: Short answer is "no". You are confusing the cursor into database table, vs. an element in your DOM.

Comment: Generally speaking, you are probably supposed to write a value into the table, probably updating a specific row's specific column. So get that value, and figure out what row and what column you're supposed to write into. If you don't understand, you really should ask earlier, as to me, you don't even understand what you're trying to accomplish, muchless finding the syntax for it.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to learn HTML, javascript and firebase in a short amount of time without any professional help. So I am quite lost, thus I'm asking questions online to find any help I can get.

Comment: I understand you are trying to learn a lot by yourself, but right now, you lack the fundamentals to understand the basics I'm trying to explain. You are just tackling too many subjects at the same time. I'd suggest you work through some HTML tutorials, spend a week on that, then spend a week on JavaScript and jQuery, THEN finally, come back and learn Firebase, which itself is a bit of weird duck in that it is a NoSQL data store (among several other things). And we've gotten WAY off topic.

Comment: @OP: I think it's not a good idea to learn firebase now, as to build anything you need a very strong foundation and that foundation is a deep understanding of the core concepts first in JS, HTML or css like an array, array method, object, object methods, ajax, async and so on.. without that you will always find your self lost as to why I am not getting any data from this callback, why I am not able to access this array data, how to get the values from nested objects & collections and so on.. I hope that make sense.

Comment: To explain what Firebase (and NoSQL db in general) is beyond the scope of this question, but in most NoSQL db, values are stored as "key" : "value" pairs. Like {"fName": "John", "lName":"Doe"}  As I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with that long string I CANNOT tell you whether that is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, hahaha! I'll take your advice and slow down a bit, I just have a lot to do in a short amount of time. Anyways, since i dont want a "submit" button, how about using onclick for each radiobutton?

Comment: It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Use addEventListener instead and that should help you. Please read this linked post for more details.

Comment: Generally, a BAD IDEA since radio buttons are supposed to work in GROUPS (sharing the same "name") thus putting different IDs on each just creates extra work for yourself. Ask yourself this: WHY do you need to write the changes back to the DB as soon as the user changed it? And is there another way, that you don't know of... because you never learned another way?

Comment: Cause the web app is synced with an android app that has the same features (e.g. the radiobuttons). So if i select a specific radiobutton on the web app, that radiobutton will be selected in the android app. Not sure if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Look up "onChange" eventlistener for your radiobutton values. But as I said already, you don't need all that fancy Javascript to do it. Not that you ever really explained what are you trying to save back into the database. Value of that field is just field.value. If you REALLY don't care about bandwidth, and need to sync your webapp with your Android app THAT closely, as both are actively listening for changes from the server and updating, I'd say the architecture may be a bit... problematic.